# Revert to first time load value from ajax on cancel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

Basically I have a display view (using span) and edit view (using input) in same page, where only display or edit view is visible to the user at one time.

Display View -> Edit Button 
Edit View -> Save Button / Cancel Button

When the user click cancel button, the page will change from edit view to display view with data loaded from ajax call.

**My question is:** 
How to preserve the first loaded ajax call value and retrieve it back when cancel button is click.

**Condition:** 
1) No calling ajax again to fetch back the value 
2) The solution should be generic and good enough to be reusable in most similar situation

I believe that this is some how a common problem face by many developer out there.

```js
function MyViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.FirstName = ko.observable();
  self.LastName = ko.observable();
  self.SelectedCountryID = ko.observable();
  
  self.GetInformation = function() {
    $.ajax({
      // get data and bind
    });
  }
  
  self.GetCountryInformation = function() {
    $.ajax({
      // get country data and bind to select option
    });
  }
 
  self.SaveInformation = function() {
    $.ajax({
      // post data
   });
  }
  
  self.OnCancelClick = function() {
    // cancel and revert back to first time load vale.
  }
  
  self.GetInformation();
  self.GetCountryInformation();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
   <!-- Display View -->
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" data-bind="value:FirstName">
  <input type="text" data-bind="value:LastName">
  <select data-bind="options: AvailableCountries,
                       optionsText: 'CountryName',
                       value: SelectedCountryID,
                       optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
 <!-- All other input -->
</div>
```

Comment: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html

Comment: @CrimsonChris will take a look on this

Answer (score 0):

Have two separate observables. On save, you copy the edit observable to the saved observable. On cancel, you don't.

```js
var vm = (function() {
  var self = {
    mode: ko.observable('Display'),
    savedValue: ko.observable(),
    newValue: ko.observable(),
    save: function (data) {
      console.debug("Save", data, self.newValue());
      self.savedValue(self.newValue());
      self.mode('Display');
    }
  };
  
  return self;
}())

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="visible:mode() == 'Display'">
  <span data-bind="text:savedValue"></span>
  <button data-bind="click:mode.bind(null, 'Edit')">Edit</button>
</div>
<div data-bind="visible:mode() == 'Edit'">
  <input data-bind="value:newValue" />
  <button data-bind="click:save">Save</button>
  <button data-bind="click:mode.bind(null, 'Display')">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be elegant solution. Will give this a try. can u justify the use of self invoking function here. Other than that, what is the first parameter for .bind() in this case? are u refering to jquery bind() over [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_bind.asp)?

Comment: That's the regular JS bind. Used to set the context of a function.

Comment: I'm using bind to curry `mode`'s set function. You can provide separate functions in the viewmodel to set mode to Edit and Display, if you prefer.